# Real binary block in XML (C++)?

Tags: c++, xml, encoding, binary

Is it possible to integrate a real (not encoded in characters) binary block (best with defined byte-order and word-length) into an XML file?

Comment: Interesting, how would one detect the end of block?

Comment: Did you try with a `<![CDATA[]]>` section? Though I doubt you can have 'real' binary data in it, since XML is basically a text oriented format.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I think the length of the block should be encoded in some attribute. The [VTK file format](http://www.vtk.org/VTK/img/file-formats.pdf) specifications allow something similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible while keeping within the xml standard.

The allowable set of characters in a parsed XML entity is tab, carriage return, linefeed, and valid unicode characters.  There are various bytes that fall outside of this allowable range, most prominently 0x0, but also 0x1 - 0x8, 0xB - 0xC, and 0xE - 0x1F (i.e., most values that are classically ASCII control characters).

You can't even include them as numeric entities, since they aren't valid characters. i.e., the following will not validate:

```
<test>
    Testing ^A: &#x1;
</test>
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#charsets